# How to restore a MSSQL database in a new location without spcifying logical names

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to use the command line to restore MSSQL databases from customer computers to my computer.

The syntax is:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDB] FROM DISK='D:BackupsMyDB.bak'  WITH 
MOVE 'AdventureWorks2008R2_Data' TO 'D:\MyData\MyAdvWorks_Data.mdf'
```

It works but each time I need to specify the logical name after MOVE because it is in another folder in the origin.
Is there a way to restore backup files in a new location without having to use the logical name?

For example, I would like something like:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDB] FROM DISK='D:BackupsMyDB.bak'  WITH 
MOVE * TO 'D:\MyData'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to move the location of the files, then you definitely need to specify the logical name.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190255.aspx

You can use the RESTORE FILELISTONLY command to find the physical and logical names if the target is another server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778.aspx

Below is a script from Greg Robidoux.  It generates restore TSQL code for a given database via the BACKUP chain.

You might be able to use it as a starting point to solve your own problem.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1243/auto-generate-sql-server-database-restore-scripts/

Good luck

Crafty DBA